# Exceptionininitializererror when using PowerMock Static

Tags: unit-testing, static, mocking, powermock, easymock

I am trying to mock a class with static methods. This class in not inside may package.
I get exceptionininitializererror.
I am using Easymock with Powermock.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please post the specific code that is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should PrepareForTest the static class:

```
@PrepareForTest({YourStaticClass.class})
public class YourTestClass{...}
```

And before you mock the static method you should use

```
mockStatic(YourStaticClass.class);
```